# How to insert output of a python for loop into an excel column?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to use a for loop to populate data in a destination column in an excel spreadsheet. The destination column gets made but then the information from the for loop doesn't print into the excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
aasb_scores = pd.read_excel ('/Users/nnamdiokoli/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Desktop/AASB Scoring PivotTable Example.xlsx', 
                             index=False) 

aasb_scores['Average'] = (aasb_scores['Q1'] + 
           aasb_scores['Q2']+ aasb_scores['Q3'] + 
           aasb_scores['Q4'] + aasb_scores['Q5'])/5.00
aasb_scores.head(10)

def finalround():
    for i in aasb_scores['Average']:
        if i >= 3:
            print('Final Round')
        else:
            print('cut')

aasb_scores['Moving on?'] = finalround()

aasb_scores.to_excel('/Users/nnamdiokoli/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Desktop/AASB Scoring PivotTable Example.xlsx',
                     index=False)
```

Comment: `print()` is used only to display on screen, not to put in variable or any other place. You should use  rather `return 'Final Round'`. But with `pandas` you should rather use its functions instead of `for`-loop - ie. `apply()`. Your function may return one value for all cells in column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` is used only to display on screen, not to put in variable or any other place.
You should use `return "Final Round"` and `return "cut"`.

But with `pandas` you should rather use its functions instead of `for`-loop - ie. `apply()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'Average': [random.randint(0,5) for _ in range(10)]})

def finalround(value):
    if value >= 3:
       return 'Final Round'
    else:
       return 'cut'

df['Moving on?'] = df['Average'].apply(finalround)

print(df)
```

or shorter with `lambda`

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'Average': [random.randint(0,5) for _ in range(10)]})

df['Moving on?'] = df['Average'].apply(lambda x: 'Final Round' if x>=3 else 'cut')

print(df)
```

---

Eventually you can create column `'Moving on?'` with default value `'cut'` and later filter rows in which you want to set `'Final Round'`

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'Average': [random.randint(0,5) for _ in range(10)]})

df['Moving on?'] = 'cut'

df['Moving on?'][ df['Average'] >= 3 ] = 'Final Round'

print(df)
```